# Limit external script to particular host group.

Tags: monitoring, zabbix, network-monitoring

Hi I am new to zabbix monitoring. I am having 3 hostgroup in my zabbix server UI,

1. host-all
2. host-blwe
3. host-train
4. host-standby

Now I am having a external script which I want to run against blwe host group. I am having a template which is linked to all host groups except host-all. Now I want to add an item which will be available to only host-blwe host group. and based on the result of that item script, it should trigger alert.

Any ideas how it is done?

Answer (score 0):

This is a rather vague question and not really answerable in the scope of this site, but it seems like you want to create a new template, include your new item in it and link the template to the hosts as needed.
For alerting, you will also have to create a trigger, referencing that item (it will show in the template).

You might want to start by reading some general introduction like https://zabbix.org/wiki/Docs/Triggers_and_Actions_and_Hosts . As you said "a template which is linked to all host groups", you might also want to read http://www.zabbixbook.com/2016/09/22/added-a-template-to-group-nothing-happened/ (disclaimer - I'm the author of the last one).